# Macro to execute only if the modification of one cell of my range is different from 0 or empty cell (event)

Tags: excel, vba, events

I have a macro in one specific sheet called “auto assegnate”

What I want to do is to execute a specific macro called macroArvalItaly. When the user modifies a cell from range E5 to E13 in  sheet “auto assegnate”, it works well. However I would like that my macro macroArvalItaly is executed only if the user modifies a cell from this range with a modification different from the value 0 or leave the cell empty (blank).

I mean if the modification of one my cell of this range (E5 to E13) equal to 0 or empty cell: do not execute the macro

If the modification of one my cell of this range (E5 to E13) is different from 0 or empty cell: execute my macro

And on the top of it (it is optional but it would be great), if the modification of one my cell of this range (E5 to E13) is different from a figure or an empty cell (the figure can be decimal like for example 0,333): do not execute the macro and send an error message to the user (“the entries from cell E5 to E13 should be only figures”)

Many Thanks in advance.
Xavi

Here please find my code below:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

With Worksheets("Auto assegnate")
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E5:E13")) Is Nothing Then

Call ThisWorkbook.macroArvalItaly1
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add an if statement that checks the value:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   With Worksheets("Auto assegnate")
       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E5:E13")) Is Nothing AND target.Value <> "" AND target.Value <> 0 Then
         Call ThisWorkbook.macroArvalItaly1
       End If
    End With
End Sub
```

For your second part if you wanted to check if it was equal to another cell just use

```
if ISNUMERIC(target.value) Then
    Call ThisWorkbook.macroArvalItaly1
Else
   msgbox "You cannot use this value"
End if
```

Comment: Thank you very much VBA_SQL_Programmer! that´s exactly what I want for the 1st part. However For the second part, it is not exactly what I want. I want the following : if the datas entered in any of my cells between E5 and E13 is not a number, then I want to display the msgbox "You cannot use this value"

Comment: @Xavi, I updated the code for your request.  The function ISNUMERIC checks the target value to see if it is a number.  If it is then the code will execute if not then you will get the msgbox

Comment: thanks you so much VBA_SQL_programmer! now my Code works perfectly, I updated it according to my Need as below:                               Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   With Worksheets("Auto assegnate")
       If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E5:E13")) Is Nothing And IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value <> "" And Target.Value <> 0 Then
         Call ThisWorkbook.macroArvalItaly1
         ElseIf Target.Value <> 0 And Target.Value <> "" Then
   MsgBox "You cannot use this value"
       End If
    End With
End Sub

Comment: @Xavi, perfect.  Can you mark the answer as accepted so others can see that the question has been resolved.

Comment: Of Course I can do it VBA_SQL_Programmer but I do not know how can I do that... Please could you tell me  how can do that? Sorry I am still quite new on this forum and I am struggled a bit with all the fonctionalities proposed...

Comment: @Xavi, no problem at all.  You should see a little check mark next to the top left of my answer.  There is a ↑ then below that a 0 then below that a ↓ and then below that a check mark.  Just click the check mark and it will turn green and that is how you approve an answer

Comment: Thanks a lot  VBA_SQL_Programmer! I did it, it is ok now.